# How to start a conversation from nodejs client to microsoft bot

Tags: node.js, azure, bots, botframework, chatbot

I'm trying to build an app that would send messages to a chat on Microsoft bot framework based on Directline lib, and reply with answer. The app is a web application where should send a POST request that should forward the message to the bot client, and reply with response of the bot from Microsoft bot framework.

An example of HTTP POST request:

http://host:port/api/message 
**BODY:** {message:"Hi"}

It should send the **"Hi"** as a text to the relevant chat bot in the Microsoft Bot framework and reply with what ever the framework replys with.

I have put the secret and done all i think i should have done in order it to be working but, i'm having problem generating a conversation that should talk with the chat bot.

This is how i did it:

```
"use strict";

require('dotenv').config();

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var http = require('http');
var postLib = require("./lib");

var messageFilePath="message.out";

var cors = require('cors');
var uuid = require('uuid');

//new botclient
var client = require('directline-api');

// config items

var pollInterval = 1000;
var directLineSecret = 'secret';
var directLineClientName = 'DirectLineClient';
var directLineSpecUrl = 'https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/swagger.json';

///bot client end


var sendmail = require('sendmail')({silent: true})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.options('*', cors()); // include before other routes
var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};

    app.post('/interact/message', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res) {
                var uuid1 = uuid.v1();
                var bodyMessage = JSON.stringify(req.body);
                var log = uuid1 + ', ' + new Date().getTime() + ", " + bodyMessage;
                if (req.query.botId == 1) {
                        emailMessage(log);
                        res.send(postLib.reply.reply);
                }
                if (req.query.botId == 2) {
                        botMessage(bodyMessage.message);
                        res.send(postLib.reply.reply);
                }

});




function emailMessage(log){

                sendmail({
                        from: postLib.mail.from,
                        to: postLib.mail.to,
                        subject: postLib.mail.subject,
                        html: 'this is the log: [' + log + ']',
                        }, function(err, reply) {
                        console.log(err && err.stack);
                        console.dir(reply);
                });


                fs.appendFile(messageFilePath, "\n" + log, function(error){
                        if (error) throw error;
                });
}


function botMessage(message){

var token = client.getToken(directLineSecret);

// create a conversation
var conversationId = client.createConversation(token);

// post a message in a conversation
client.postMessage(token, conversationId, {
                text: message
            });
return client.getMessage(token, conversationId, 0);
}

var server = app.listen(8082, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("interact post server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear the issue that you are having but I recommend you to check the [Node.js Direct Line sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine).

Comment: I checked it already and didn't manage to solve what I want. Let me try to re explain. I want to be able to send from http client a post request with text in the body as json , so it will pass the message through the bot client and should  response with the bot reply.

Comment: But using DirectLine? or the REST API to talk with bots? you are not explaining what's your issue

Comment: I want to have my own rest API service exposed to support a simple conversation, so when you send a a simple standard POST request with the message within it will pass the message through the bot client. The bot client should talk with Microsoft frameworks bot with direct line api. It's kind another layer of conversation , a simpler layer that I'm trying to build.

Comment: Right, again not clear what;s the issue then. the Direct Line layer is already built in the sample I sent you so it just a matter of adding your layer on top of it

Comment: i have tried the example you attached above with my http above it and it didn't work...
i've added the exception i'm getting when i used that approach

Comment: i have updated my question and i hope it's more clear now.
please see if now one of you can advise @ezequiel